# Getting value inside a tag in react from event.target

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-table

I just encountered a problem if anyone could help me in this it would be great!!

here's a code i am working on

```js
const loc = props.filtered.map((item,i)=>{
  if(typeof props.filtered[i].scan != "undefined"){
    return props.filtered[i].scan.map((items,idx)=>{
      return <li>{props.filtered[i].scan[idx].location}</li>
    })
  }
})
```

In this code you can see that it returns a li tag with information inside.

Now the problem is that i am putting all this data inside a table a basic HTML one. Now as soon i have a onClick function on Tr and do event.target i get

"the required data"

instead i want only the data instead of the data with li tags

also the typeOf is showing that it is a object

here is the onclick code

```html
<table className="table ">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">AWBNO</th>
    <th scope="col">TRANSPORTER</th>
    <th scope="col">SOURCE</th>
    <th scope="col">DESTINATION</th>
    <th scope="col">Start</th>
    <th scope="col">ETD</th>
    <th scope="col">Status</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>

    <td onClick={click} id="test" className="try">{awb}</td>
    
    <td>{Transporter}</td>
    <td>{Source}</td>
    <td>{Destination}</td>
    <td>{start}</td>

    <td>{etd}</td>
    <td className="forstatus">{status}</td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### EDIT:

`onClick`-function:

```
function click (event){ 
    var y = document.getElementById("test").innerText; 
    console.log(y) console.log( event.target.value) 
}
```

Comment:  Can you please post the code for your `{click}` function? How things are wired up in your code and the specific expected/actual result aren't quite clear.

Comment: @Derek here's the code                                                                                    
   function click  (event){
          
           var y  = document.getElementById("test").innerText;
           console.log(y)
            console.log( event.target.value)
            
        }

Comment: i tried using both document method and event.target method but none of them seen to work when i use event.target one i get something like this <li>"the data"<li> instead i want only "data"

Comment: Am I interpreting you correctly that you want the `click` function to return the values from your original `map` (`{props.filtered[i].scan[idx].location}`) that end up getting rendered within `li` elements?

Comment: @Derek Yes its correct

Comment: Since you're already programmatically populating the `td`, is there some reason you need to get the data from the rendered element instead of storing the data in a variable or a state once you've parsed it into `loc`?